# How to filter datetime property by Today in OData

Tags: c#, datetime, odata

I have record with DateTime property (property name is Date):

```
new Student
            {
                Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                Name = name,
                Score = score,
                Date = DateTime.Now,
            }
```

I am trying to get records which Date is equal to todays date. I executed some queries:

```
https://localhost:44383/odata/Student?$filter=Date +eq + now()
https://localhost:44383/odata/Student?$filter=Date +eq + date(now())
https://localhost:44383/odata/Student?$filter=date(Date) +eq + date(now())
```

But all of them are not working. I couldn't find anything in documentation. How can I build this kind of query?

Comment: Every server is different.  You have to check the server you are using to see what format it accepts.  A URL is text and you cannot send a DateTime (which is a number) on the URL.  The text has to be in a format that the server will recognize and parse into a DateTime.

Comment: @jdweng, It is console app, should something be changed in configuration?

Comment: The parameters for the query are after the question mark in the URL.  The parameters must be text in a format that the server recognizes.

Comment: @jdweng, Can you show the URL that you mean?

Comment: The URL are your queries : https://localhost:44383/odata/Student?

Comment: @jdweng what is wrong with this?

Comment: What is the actual string in the URL is it "https://localhost:44383/odata/Student?$filter=Date +eq + now()"  or https://localhost:44383/odata/Student?$filter=Dateeq3/15/2021"? The second is with the variables replace with actual values.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229939/discussion-between-dilshod-k-and-jdweng).